# How to bind dynamic content to document-ready events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am not amazing with jQuery or JavaScript for that matter, so there is probably a duplicate question on this, but I am not sure how to phrase my search. I think I have to use `.trigger()` or `on()` but I am not sure how to implement it properly if so, or perhaps it's not possible in this scenario.

I have three pages, my `index.php` page with HTML, a `dispatch.php` page that serves dynamic content into the index page via Ajax, and lastly `scripts.js` with all my jQuery/JavaScript.

Here is psuedo-code example:

**/index.php**

```
<form id="form1">
    <input type="text" name="whatever" />
    <input type="submit" name="whatever_submit" disabled="disabled" class="enable" />
</form>
<form id="form2">
    <input type="text" name="whatever2" />
    <input type="submit" name="whatever_submit2" disabled="disabled" class="enable" />
</form>
<!-- this is where the dispatch page will deliver content to -->
<div id="drophere"></div>
```

**/js/scripts.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Runs on page load and enables all the submit buttons
    $('.enable').attr('disabled',false);
    // Code to dispatch
    $.ajax({
        url: '/dispatch.php',
        ....ect
});
```

**/dispatch.php**

```
<!-- Does php stuff, sends back this additional form -->
<form id="form3">
    <input type="text" name="whatever3" />
    <input type="submit" name="whatever_submit3" disabled="disabled" class="enable" />
</form>
```

The issue here is that the jQuery `$('.enable').attr('disabled',false);` works on `form1` and `form2` but now I am using ajax to load a form and it doesn't bind to the dynamic `form3` because the other two are effected on document-ready. I successfully use `on.()` for interactive elements because there is a trigger *(`click`, `mouseover`, etc)* but it's this passive application that I don't really know how to do *(maybe there is no way or maybe I am not calling the right event type?)*. As a workaround, I put the same enabling script into the dispatched html:

```
<form id="form3">
    <input type="text" name="whatever3" />
    <input type="submit" name="whatever_submit3" disabled="disabled" class="enable" />
</form>
<!--
So this is added at the bottom and runs as soon as the content loads to
the index.php page
-->
<script>
$('.enable').attr('disabled',false);
</script>
```

This seems like a clumsy workaround, so is there a proper way to bind dynamic content to a document-ready event from javascript located on `scripts.js` or is the proper way to redo that piece of code to work on a click event using `on()` similar to:

```
$(document).on('click','.enable',function(){
    $(this).attr('disabled',false);
    // Possibly do the form submit here...whatever I get to work
});
```

I am hoping there is a way to bind because I have a lot of other similar instances this will apply to, but I am thinking I may have to switch to per-click basis? Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Just run the line after the ajax call ?

Comment: @DaniP Ok, so there is way to natively bind that without user interaction or manually I take it? There is automation involved in the ajax script and there are other instances where this scenario applies so I was trying to avoid hardcoding for each specific event, but it sounds like I have to do it that way. I was hoping I could make a listener like `$(document).on('ready','.enable'....etc` or something. Even that would be better but from what you are saying I may be SOL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just execute the `$('.enable').attr('disabled',false);` in the callback function of the ajax-call.

What you could do is using the MutationObserver which is part of modern browser JS engines: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: Sorry, as I noted in my comment to @DaniP, I was hoping for a bind-type way to do it after the element is loaded into the page, there are any number of ways I can do it, ajax callback, as you noted, being one.

Comment: From what you both have said, it sounds like there is no way to bind dynamic content to document-ready elements using an `.on()` type method.

Comment: What you could do is using the MutationObserver which is part of modern browser JS engines: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: That actually does sound like what I am talking about. I will investigate that, it looks promising. If I can't get it to work, other than what's been suggested is the correct answer so I'll just mark yours as correct for now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are appending form html data to document. So in ajax function you need to find newly added button and then you can disable it easily.
As like below code.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        // Runs on page load and enables all the submit buttons
        $('.enable').attr('disabled',false);
        // Code to dispatch
        $.ajax({
            url: '/dispatch.php',
            ...#drophere
            success: function(data) {
            $('#drophere').html(data);
            // find and disable button 
            $('#drophere').find('.enable').attr('disabled',false);
        }
    });
```